# How to export text file using python in win7 command prompt

Tags: python

I have a command like this ".exe abcd >c:\filename.txt" in command prompt I run then need to press two times enter button then filename.txt getting the value but I used

```
os.system(".exe abcd >c:\filename.txt")
```

then file becomes empty how to resolve this issue using python

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) module to create the process. Use the arguments of `call` to specify the standard input, output and error streams.

Example:

```
with open('somefile.txt','w') as f:
    subprocess.call(["command.exe", "abcd"], stdout=f)
```